# detect resolution information (txtrecord) changes by JmDNS

Tags: android, jmdns

JmDNS support service listener which include method for added services `serviceAdded` (detect new services) and include a method for removed sevices `serviceRemoved` (detect removed services).

my question is: are there a method which detect service data modification of existing service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`serviceResolved` method detect service data modification (txtrecord)